# How to have only one page in a rails project be linked to a certain stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have a controller `main_pages` in a rails project that holds two views: `home.html` and `team.html`. All my css and styling for `home` and `team` has gone into `main_pages.css.scss`, but I would like to separate some of the styling that is specific to each of those pages into respective css stylesheets, such as `home.css.scss` and `team.css.scss`. Creating these stylesheets is not an issue, but how would I go about linking them?

I don't even know how `home.html` and `team.html` are linked with `main_pages.css.scss`, since I don't see any code in the header of `application.html` that links the two. Could someone explain how this link is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `application.html.erb`, add the following snippet somewhere in the `head` section:

```
<head>
  <%= content_for?(:custom_styles) ? yield(:custom_styles) : '' %>
</head>
```

And then in your view file (e.g `home.html.erb`), you can add custom stylesheets to the current view with:

```
<% content_for :custom_styles do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "custom_stylesheet_name" %>
<% end %>
```

Now everything you add to the content_for block in the page view file will be added to the header, so if you add a stylesheet link tag it will also be added to the header.